# Alternative to Numpy's @ multiplication in DOK-matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a sparse DOK-matrix called `occurrences` and a Numpy matrix `occurrences_np`, which both count the occurrences of words in documents. Now, I want to get the cooccurrences and want to obtain this by multiplying occurence's transpose with occurrences.

With `occurrences_np`, I have done this as follows:

`np.transpose(occurrences_np) @ occurrences_np`

However, when I try:

```
occurrences.multiply(occurrences.transpose())
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-160-5bd1761dd328>", line 185, in create_cooccurrences
    cooccurrences = self.occurrences.multiply(self.occurrences.transpose())

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 336, in multiply
    return self.tocsr().multiply(other)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 406, in multiply
    raise ValueError("inconsistent shapes")
```

How can I do matrix multiplications with DOK-matrices?

Comment: You should be able to use `@` with a `dok_matrix` instance, e.g. `occurrences.transpose() @ occurrences`.  Did that not work?

Comment: Sparse matrix `.multiply()` is element-wise, not dot product.

Comment: @CJR are there other options working with sparse matrices?